# how to do performance testing Apache Ignite using jmeter

Tags: docker, jmeter, performance-testing, apacheignite

I am testing to find out the performance of Apche Ignite in displaying data with a load test scenario to see he Throughput, Latency, Resource utilization and Error Rate, how do I do this test using the jmeter tool?

i hope you can give me step by step to do this testing

Answer (score 0):

There is a [JDBC Driver](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/JDBC/jdbc-driver) for Apache Ignite, you can drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and then after JMeter restart you will be able to use it in the [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)

Once you set up your JDBC URL, credentials and so on you can add [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler and put your query there.

Run your test in GUI mode with 1-2 users/iterations to ensure that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing by looking into queries output in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. If you're happy with results add more users and [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode), this way you will get metrics for the increased load.

Comment: i do this testing in localhost server, can i do this testing